# How do I static_assert that a value parsed as const& is the right type?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::list<int> const& some_sequence)
    {
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(some_sequence),std::list<int>>::value ,
        "some_sequence should be an integer list"
        );
    }
```

How do I make the static assert work? The important thing is that the type is an integer list.
Cheers.

Comment: I'm a little confused: `some_sequence` has type `const std::list<int>&` -- what other type are you concerned that it might be?

Comment: @NateKohl: the check is there to remind other programmers that there are structural reasons for the type being `list`, and that they shouldn't be changed just because profiling finds them too slow.

Comment: Why not a comment then?

Comment: Because comments can't bite back.

Comment: IMO a comment would be more clear and could explain why it needs to be that way.  The assert is something I'd see and think it was a noob mistake since it could never fail.

Comment: I can see why you'd think that, but I don't agree that comments are better suited. I use comments to explain *why* I am doing things and the *purpose* of using certain types. If I want to *ensure* that a type or value should be constrained in some way, I use `static_assert` and `assert` respectively. I think it's a neat way of doing things and it draws a distinction between an *explanation* (comment) and an *assertion* (assert). Each to their own I suppose.

Comment: By the way in my actual code such trivial examples don't really exist, the `static_assert` is placed near the location where the reason for that type being thus is located, which is often not near the declaration of the type.

Comment: It's your code, but I still believe an explanation is more useful than the assert.  After all, the assert can just be removed or commented out if it's seen to be superfluous.  Believe me, I've seen plenty of bugs where someone changed something, including removing important checks just because they didn't understand why something was the way it was.

Comment: Yeah, so even in this instance the onus is still on me to write a good explanation I guess.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Luckily, `static_assert` was built so you can put the explanation right there next to the assertion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use `static_assert(...)`: the compiler will make sure that this function is called with a `std::list<int>`. If you want to make the above code compile, you need to use

```
MyClass::MyClass(std::list<int> const& some_sequence)
{
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(some_sequence),std::list<int> const&>::value ,
        "some_sequence should be an integer list"
    );
}
```

`some_sequence` is declared as `std::list<int> const&` and that is the type obtained by `decltype(some_sequence)`. This `static_assert()` will never fail, however.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to place the `const&`!

Comment: And yeah I'm using these static asserts to remind myself and others that there the container type is structurally important and that the program will fail is you use a vector (for example). This is to stop someone later on deciding to change the type for performance reasons.